# AWS API Gateway Javascript SDK Returns 404 Not Found

Tags: aws-api-gateway

When I call my AWS API Gateway from a JavaScript client I get a 404 not found error because the SDK invokes the wrong endpoint:

- https://www.myserver.com/abc123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/status

Instead of

- https://abc123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/status

It was fine yesterday. Someone can explain the cause?

UPDATE!

In axios.standalone.js a Microsoft.XMLHTTP ActiveX object is created to send the request. The `data` parameter has a `url` member set to "https:abc123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/status". Note there is no slash slash at the beginning. The base URL of the JavaScript client is inserted into the request URL. Please help!

Comment: My JavaScript client resides on my server (for example https://www.myserver.com)

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the JS SDK generator that has been fixed recently. Please update your JS SDK with a newly generated version.

Best,
Jurgen

Answer (score 0):

Modify axios.standalone.js

```
module.exports = function xhrAdapter(resolve, reject, config) {

      // Temporary fix for missing // in config.url 
      if ((config.url.substr(0, 6) == "https:") && (config.url.substr(0, 8) != "https://")) {     
        config.url = "https://" + config.url.substr(6, config.url.length - 6);
      }

...
```